Combine drag & drop with multiple item selection using QTreeWidget
I have QTreeWidget with ExtendedSelection (multiple seleciton). When i try to add drag & drop functionality to QTreeWidget using setDragEnabled(true);, the multiple selections stops work because DnD functionality.
My code is
#include <QApplication>
#include <QTreeWidget>

class MyTreeWidget : public QTreeWidget {
public:
    MyTreeWidget(QWidget *parent = nullptr) : QTreeWidget(parent) {
        setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::ExtendedSelection);
        //setDragEnabled(true);
        QTreeWidgetItem *item1 = new QTreeWidgetItem(this, QStringList() << "Item 1");
        QTreeWidgetItem *item2 = new QTreeWidgetItem(this, QStringList() << "Item 2");
        QTreeWidgetItem *item3 = new QTreeWidgetItem(this, QStringList() << "Item 3");
        addTopLevelItem(item1);
        addTopLevelItem(item2);
        addTopLevelItem(item3);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    MyTreeWidget treeWidget;
    treeWidget.setGeometry(100, 100, 400, 300);
    treeWidget.show();

    return app.exec();
}

My question is how can i enable both multiple selection and drag & drop functionality together like in Windows?

What gesture are you using for multiple selection?

@Eljay i am using mouse for multiple seleciton (left click + mouse move)

Since drag is based on click+move, how would you differentiate when the user wants to drag or select? It seems quite obvious that you can't have both, because they are incompatible.

The left click + mouse move is the drag-and-drop gesture when you have drag enabled.  Use one of the other multiple selection gestures.

@musicamante In windows file explorer both of them works fine

@Eljay for example?

I used left click to select an item, and then shift+click on another item to extend the selection.  Then I used cmd+click to select one more item that was discontiguous from the other extended selection set.

@SamuelSmith No: if you press the mouse on the file name, it will begin a drag. What you're probably referring to is the rubber band selection, which is a very different thing.

@musicamante No. If you press the mouse on the unselected file name and start moving mouse, it will begin rubber band selection

Just to clarify, what you're saying is that you want the left-button-press functionality to depend on whether or not the item under the mouse is currently selected?  If it is selected start a drag operation otherwise start a selection operation, right?

@G.M. Absolutely right

@SamuelSmith Maybe they changed that in Windows 11 (in Windows 10 I can still see the expected behavior, at least in icon or detail views) or it's caused by a custom setting. In any case, you shouldn't assume everybody is familiar with that peculiar selection mode, and you should instead [edit] your question and explain in detail what behavior you specifically want. In any case, a simple solution would be to override mousePressEvent() and eventually set/unset the drag mode depending on whether the indexAt() is in the selectedIndexes() or not, before calling the base implementation.

@SamuelSmith Hi, I can't reproduce your issue : exampleWorksFine with the exact same code as yours

@AmirHammoutene What specific Windows/Qt version do you have?

Windows 11, Qt 6.7.1
